# file name containing M-dash breaks batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, codepages

I have a batch file to process file names, but if it contains a certain non-standard "M" dash I can't assign it to a variable.  The following, for example, results in the variable VAR1 being blank:

```
set "VAR1=Sales — March.doc"
echo "%VAR1%"
```

I tried switching from code page 437 to 1252 but that didn't help. This is driving me crazy.  I can't even write a batch file to change the problematic M-dash!

Comment: What editor/encoding do you use to save the batch file? My editor (TextPad) tell me it is unicode+2014. You could try to rename with `ren "Sales ? March.doc" "Sales - March.doc"`

Comment: I have no problems echoing the variable.  Although it does change the dash to `"Sales ù March.doc"`

Comment: I use AkelPad to save the batch file, but I didn't see an entry for Unicode in the "Save As" dialog's codepage list.   And unfortunately the file names aren't constructed uniformly enough that I can devise a simple rename command (the M dashes are all over the place).

Comment: Correction:  I did try saving as UTF-8, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Found a solution.  Saving as UTF-8 and changing the codepage with "CHCP 65001" at the start of the batch file did the trick.